# How to calculate age from date with Zend_Date

Tags: php, date, zend-framework

How can I calculate age from born date using Zend_Date object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is another way you can calculate age. It uses the PHP format. It simply subtracts the years and then checks if this years birthday has passed or not. This can just as easy be done with standard PHP functions but I decided to use Zend_Date like you asked.

**Updated Answer**

```
    Zend_Date::setOptions(array(
        'format_type' => 'php'
    ));
    $today           = new Zend_Date();
    $dateOfBirth     = new Zend_Date('1979-04-10', 'Y-m-d');

    $age             = $today->toString('Y') - $dateOfBirth->toString('Y');
    // Edit: Added julian date adjustments for leap years
    $adjustJulian    = strcmp($today->toString('L'), $dateOfBirth->toString('L'));
    if ($dateOfBirth->toString('m') > 2) {
        $dateOfBirth->addDay($adjustJulian);
    }

    if ($today->toString('z') < $dateOfBirth->toString('z')) {
        $age--;
    }
```

Thanks to [@maciej-homziuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317107/maciej-homziuk) for pointing out the leap year limitations of the previous answer. I have updated this answer adding adjustments for the julian day for leap years.

Comment: That `Zend_Date::setOptions` string makes the code unusable for me - it ruins all the date formatting after the age function is called.

Comment: @yentsun Thats because it changes the default options prior to the execution of the code. You can change it back once you have the date Zend_Date::setOptions(array('format_type' => 'iso'))

Comment: yeah, I fixed that in my code already. I though you might mention it in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to use this function:

```
public function getAge($dob)
{
    $today = new Zend_Date();
    $dob   = new Zend_Date($dob, Tuffle_Date::getDBFormat());

    $y = Zend_Date::YEAR;
    $m = Zend_Date::MONTH;
    $d = Zend_Date::DAY;

    $dobCurrentYear = new Zend_Date($today->get($y) . '-' . $dob->get($m) . '-' . $dob->get($d), Tuffle_Date::getDBFormat());
    $dobCurrentYear->setYear($today->get('Y'));

    $age = $today->get($y) - $dob->get($y);

    if (!$dobCurrentYear->isLater($today)) {
        $age--;
    }

    return $age;
}
```

Comment: in ZF1, this 'Tuffle_Date::getDBFormat()' gives fatal error so I removed this and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class designed to calculate age from zend date (see 1st reply) :
http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=6932

Answer (score 0):

FROM this post : [how to calculate a difference between two Zend_Date objects, in months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032101/how-to-calculate-a-difference-between-two-zend-date-objects-in-months)

If I read the docs correctly, there's no implemented functionality for getting difference between 2 dates in seconds/minutes/.../months/years, so you'll need to calculate it yourself. Something like this will do (dunno if it takes leap years, DST and such into consideration):

```
<?php
$birth = new Zend_Date('1988-25-06');    
$today = new Zend_Date();
$diff = $today->sub($birth)->toValue();
$age = floor($diff / 3600 / 24 / 365);
```

Comment: Does the _toValue_ method returns the number of seconds? The [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/_Date.html#%5CZend_Date::toValue()) only say that it returns an integer representation of the object.

Answer (score 0):

This is note the Zend_Date way of doing it but seems to work fine:

```
$birthdate = "1975-04-14";<br />
$age = floor((time() - strtotime($birthdate)) / 31556926);

echo "You are " . $age . " years old today.";
```

Comment: Is this considering leap years?

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = new Zend_Date();
$dateOfBirth = new Zend_Date('1988-25-06');
$age = $today->toString('Y') - $dateOfBirth->toString('Y');
if ($today->toString('dd') + $today->toString('MM') * 32 <
    $dateOfBirth->toString('dd') + $dateOfBirth->toString('MM') * 32)
    $age--;
```

Comment: Previous example "$today->toString('z') < $dateOfBirth->toString('z')" has mistake, where 'z' is timezone. 'MM' - is month, 'dd' - is day, and we need to check if birthday have already celebrated this year: "not celebrated" = (M < M or (M = M and D < D)) simplified to M * 32 + D < M * 32 + D.

Comment: If this is a correction on a previous answer it should be a comment on that answer rather than a new answer. Also it is advised to always explain your code.

Answer (score 0):

I like brady.vitrano's approach very much and it was also the base to build my own action helper calculating age in years, however his code is not considering leap years (f.e. if  date of birth is the 1979-03-09 [common year] and today is 2012-03-08 [leap year], his method returns 33 although the real age is 32) - that's how it has to be extended to return correct age when leap years are involved:

```
Zend_Date::setOptions(array(
    'format_type' => 'php'
));

$today = new Zend_Date();
$dateOfBirth = new Zend_Date($date);

/*** Considering the leap years if the birth date is on 1st march or later. ***/
if ($dateOfBirth->toString('n') > 2) {
    $birthLeap = $dateOfBirth->toString('L');
    $todayLeap = $today->toString('L');
}

$age = $today->toString('Y') - $dateOfBirth->toString('Y');

if ($today->toString('z') - $todayLeap < $dateOfBirth->toString('z') - $birthLeap) {
    $age--;
}
```

And this is the code if you want to work with Zend's default date specifier (rather than PHP's date specifier):

```
$today = new Zend_Date();
$dateOfBirth = new Zend_Date($date);

/*** Considering the leap years if the birth date is on 1st march or later. ***/
if ($dateOfBirth->get('M') > 2) {
    /*** Checking if the birth's year is a leap year. ***/
    if ($dateOfBirth->get(Zend_Date::LEAPYEAR)) {
        $birthLeap = 1;
    }

    /*** Checking if today's year is a leap year. ***/
    if ($today->get(Zend_Date::LEAPYEAR)) {
        $todayLeap = 1;
    }
}

$age = $today->get('Y') - $dateOfBirth->get('Y');

if ($today->get('D') - $todayLeap < $dateOfBirth->get('D') - $birthLeap) {
    $age--;
}
```

Comment: I double checked my answer using `$today = new Zend_Date('2012-03-08'); $dateOfBirth = new Zend_Date('1979-03-09');` and it returned 32 just as you said it should. However, I did find does cause a problem for today Feb 29 and DOB Mar 1. What is your servers date.timezone setting?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my answer with the correction for leap years.